# Optimization of sum of squares over permutations

Tags: optimization, permutations, sums-of-squares, rearrangement-inequality

Suppose I have fixed, positive values $n_1, \cdots, n_\ell$ and $T$. I'm looking for an algorithm to optimize
\begin{align*}
f(\boldsymbol{n}) = T\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\ell}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{j}n_i\right)^2\right) - \left(\sum_{j=1}^{\ell}\sum_{i=1}^{j}n_i\right)^2
\end{align*}
Over all permutations of the elements in $\boldsymbol{n} = (n_1, \cdots, n_\ell)$. I've figured out the coefficients in the expansion of $f(\boldsymbol{n})$, specifically
\begin{align*}
[n_i^2]f(\boldsymbol{n}) = T(\ell - i + 1) -(\ell - i + 1)^2 \qquad \text{and} \qquad [n_i n_j] f(\boldsymbol{n}) = 2T(\ell - i\vee j + 1) - 2(\ell - i + 1)(\ell - j + 1)
\end{align*}
where $[x]f(\boldsymbol{x})$ denotes the coefficient of $x$ in the expansion of $f(\boldsymbol{x})$, and $i \vee j = \max(i,j)$. How should I proceed from here?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly. First, the second term seems to be constant and irrelevant -- why are you including it? Second, isn't it obvious that you should just arrange the $n_i$ in ascending/descending order to minimize/maximize the first term? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @joriki, I just corrected a typo in the second term; it's a sum of a running sum which makes matching the ascending order a bit more difficult